# too many DrupalDatabaseCache::set

Tags: mysql, caching, drupal, drupal-7

One of my websites made with drupal 7 and a couple of modules, block and views today started to be really slow.

I'was checking devel and i saw 600 query for an empty page (that means that there are no block, views or content).
Many of this queryes are made by "DrupalDatabaseCache::set", i have the cache enabled and with 30 mins lifetime, so the second time that i load the empty page i mus tsee cache get but not set.

Anybody can help me understanding  why this webiste has so many queryes and why it keep setting caches?

Comment: You should never use devel on a production site.

Comment: you right but i had to, because was toooooo slow :(

Answer (score 0):

I found that was views, one block generate 100 queries...

I asked for a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944407/simple-drupal-view-generate-up-to-100-queries